# Solutions to a system of diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

The system in question is: $x+y^b=y+z^c=z+x^a$ where $x,y,z$ are odd primes that are pairwise distinct and $a,b,c$ are positive integers.

From basic rearrangement I found that from $a,b,c$ only one can be even, this can be seen with:

$x+y^{2b} = y + z^{2c}$
$\rightarrow y^{2b} - z^{2c} = y - x \rightarrow (y^{b} - z^{c})(y^b + z^c) = y - x$

Which is not possible, there is a little more work that needs to be done to show this for all combinations though. This is where I got stuck.

Is such a system possible? And are there any methods to make progress on this problem?

Comment: Many variables ! Which range did you check ?

Comment: Must $x,y,z$ be pairwise distinct ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated it x,y,z should be pairwise distinct, thanks! About the range checked, I will be honest I haven't made a program to check it, I've been trying to tackle it using some factorization

Comment: Quick and dirty programming in Sage gives no hits using odd primes below $100$ and exponents up to $20$. While there's no guarantee that there are no larger solutions... well, it would seem unlikely. I do get quite a few solutions where *one* equality holds, the smallest one being $19 + 3^2 = 3 +5^2$